# Orchard 1.8 - Saving record with unique field

Tags: save, unique, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, irepository

I defined in my migration one of the columns of my table as unique. If I try to save a record that violates this uniqueness constraint of course I receive an exception:

```
A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index.
```

To save the record I'm using the IRepository Create and Update methods, because it does not have a corresponding part. After receiving the exception above I catch it and then I launch AddModelError to stop the saving procedure. Neverthless Orchard gives me another exception after that:

```
[AssertionFailure: null id in MyModule.Models.MyRecord entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)]
   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.CheckId(Object obj, IEntityPersister persister, Object id, EntityMode entityMode) +267
   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.GetValues(Object entity, EntityEntry entry, EntityMode entityMode, Boolean mightBeDirty, ISessionImplementor session) +95
   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.OnFlushEntity(FlushEntityEvent event) +139
   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.FlushEntities(FlushEvent event) +448
   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.FlushEverythingToExecutions(FlushEvent event) +283
   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.OnAutoFlush(AutoFlushEvent event) +84
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.AutoFlushIfRequired(ISet`1 querySpaces) +471
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results) +477
   NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression, QueryParameters parameters) +223
   NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionQueryImpl.List() +189
   NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.ExecuteQuery(NhLinqExpression nhLinqExpression, IQuery query, NhLinqExpression nhQuery) +61
   NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +262
   NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +26
   Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator() +83
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) +173
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector) +125
   Orchard.Data.Migration.DataMigrationManager.GetFeaturesThatNeedUpdate() +311
   Orchard.Modules.Data.Migration.<GetNotifications>d__6.MoveNext() +219
   System.Linq.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext() +507
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +536
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +80
   Orchard.UI.Admin.Notification.NotificationManager.GetNotifications() +151
   Orchard.UI.Admin.Notification.AdminNotificationFilter.OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext) +380
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +245
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +241
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +19
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   Orchard.Mvc.Routes.HttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +95
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

If I understand correctly what is causing it, Orchard automatically tries to flush the record into the database even if I add a model error. I tried to change the transaction scope but it didn't work. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure if you are alble to do it with the Repository, but usually you do `_transactionManager.Cancel()`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I have already tried and I receive the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `Unique` constraint when dealing with content part records. The reason is that those are created early, when no data has been passed to it yet (with all properties being empty/null). This happens inside `ContentManager`. Hence, all properties on those kinds of records need to be nullable and non-unique.

But you can use the unique/not-null constraints on classes that are mapped to records you create and use via `IRepository` directly.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a ContentPart and you have a way of creating a unique value for your field in .NET, then you can always use an OnInitializing event in your ContentHandler for your part.

For example, this works for a unique Sku field in the db:

```
public class ProductPartHandler: ContentHandler
{
    public ProductPartHandler(IRepository<ProductPartRecord> repository)
    {
        Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));
        OnInitializing<ProductPart>((context, part) =>
        {
            part.Sku = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        });
    }
}
```

As long as you can produce a guaranteed unique value of some sort that your field supports, then you can always set it in the handler to deal with the unique constraint and then update it later with the real value you desire.